# How can I share a link with specific users using the Share Dialog from Android/iOS Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I want to enable a user to share a link with a specific set of Facebook friends. How do I specify the privacy level (i.e. list of user ids) when launching the native Share Dialog from either the iOS or Android Facebook SDK?

Comment: It's not possible with the Share dialog, you have to implement the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)

Comment: what do you mean by "implement the facebook sdk"? do you mean use the Graph API?

Comment: I guess @Mattia Franchetto means that you have to add the Facebook iOS SDK into your project and use their controls

Comment: @IvanKonov I am using the SDK, as stated in my question's title. Where do you specify the user IDs when using the SDK?